# Calculating min and max timeperiod in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

My data has 7 products, product 1 achieved 100K sales in 2nd week and product 5 in 7 weeks. I need to show min. weeks to achieve 100K as 2 and max. week to achieve 100K as 5 across list of products I have in data. Can anyone help on the code to be used in calculated field?

Comment: Hardly. Try to show what your database looks like, and what end-product you have in mind. Some of the work you have already tried could be useful too

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using table calcs to show when a running total crosses a threshold http://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5451